# Is it ok to provide external links (not embed) to YouTube videos behind a paywall?

Tags: youtube

I am setting up a website for families to discover the world, one country of the week at a time, through print materials that I create and through other content we find online that is kid/family safe.

Families would subscribe to the program receiving a weekly delivery of original print content I've created and access to an online community forum where they can discuss that weeks country and share additional links to resources their kids enjoyed.

I understand that I am not allowed to embed YouTube links behind a paywall, but is it ok for me to send my users to external links on YouTube? (i.e. "We really liked this video [link to video] where Sam and Dave explored the ruins of fill-in-the-blank.")

I believe this is ok, but just want to be sure before launching the site later this month.

Comment: To clarify, these are 3rd party videos, that you have no control over? And the creator of the video has no idea you are doing this?

Comment: Correct, I have no control over them. I do plan on reaching out to the content creators to let them know that we've enjoyed their videos (my family and I) and that through this website, I send people to their channel to also check out their content. My long term goal, is that I would actually employ a selection of these individuals to create content for future versions of this platform.

Answer (score 1):

> I understand that I am not allowed to embed YouTube links behind a paywall

That's not true for your use case, from what I gathered from their terms of service. You are selling access to your content (print materials) which includes a video available on YouTube; you are not selling access to YouTube.

> I believe this is ok, but just want to be sure before launching the site later this month.

If you want to be sure, you can read their terms [here](https://www.youtube.com/t/terms).

Comment: That's a great point of view Warren. Thanks for that perspective. I've read through a bunch of YouTube documentation now and I'm generally pretty decent at wading through "legalese" but I was struggling to clearly see the information that might apply to me. I've been erring on the side of caution and appreciate your input here. For the time being, I think I'll just link to YouTube so that people are sent there at my recommendation and then I'll reach out to YouTube after launch to see if I am allowed to embed. I'd rather play it safe.

Comment: @DaveTernier Sure thing, that's a good plan. Playing it safe when it comes to legal matters is never a bad idea.